# Change the colour of this input text depending on the value being entered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this input text:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="newPrice">New Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newPrice" name="newPrice" placeholder="New price">
</div>
```

I would like to change the border of the input dynamically as the user is typing depending what the value is.

This value will be a percent based on an earlier defined amount that will change depending on the value the user is adding.

So if the value is under 5% it's red between 5-10% it's amber and over 10% is green etc.

Any JavaScript whizzes out there know the best way to do this?

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (the JavaScript code using jQuery), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Comment: What is "whizzes" ?

Comment: @R3tep in this context it's slang for 'experts'

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go with 2 events. The first is `input`, but `contenteditable` elements won't fire an input event on IE11, so I'll go for `keypress` with a timeout too.

`input` will be fired right after a user inputs something and the value is changed. `keypress` will fire after a user inputs something but right before the value is changed, in between.

This way you will keep all modern and older browsers covered (to a limit, because of `addEventListener`):

```
var tim = null;
var el = document.getElementById("newPrice");
el.addEventListener("keypress", function() {
    tim = setTimeout(input, 0);
});
el.addEventListener("input", function input() {
    clearTimeout(tim);
    // do whatever you want with el.value
    if (el.value == "BLAH") {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else if (parseInt(el.value) > 10) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else if (parseInt(el.value) < -12) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "whizzeblue";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment this has really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="txt" type="number" onkeyup="changeborder(this.id, this.value)" />

<script type="text/javascript">

function changeborder(id, value){
    if(value < 5){
        document.getElementById(id).style.border = "2px solid red";
    }
    else if(value > 5 && value < 10 ){
        document.getElementById(id).style.border = "2px solid yellow";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment

Answer (score 0):

Use `focusout` . In snippet validation is not applied.

```js
$("#newPrice")
  .focusout(function() {
    var price = $(this).val();
    if (parseInt(price) <= 5) {
      $(this).removeClass('green');
      $(this).removeClass('blue');
      $(this).addClass('red');
    }
    if (parseInt(price) > 5 && parseInt(price) <= 10) {
      $(this).removeClass('red');
      $(this).removeClass('blue');
      $(this).addClass('green');
    }
    if (parseInt(price) > 10) {
      $(this).removeClass('green');
      $(this).removeClass('red');
      $(this).addClass('blue');
    }
  });
```

```css
.red {
  border: solid 2px red;
}

.green {
  border: solid 2px green;
}

.blue {
  border: solid 2px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="newPrice">New Price</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newPrice" name="newPrice" placeholder="New price">
</div>
```